# biblatex-apa sorting issue

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am having an issue with `biblatex-apa` where two works of the same author does not follow chronological order, from earliest to most recent.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

```
@thesis{test1,
  author = {Doe, John},
  year = 2022,
  title = {Test title},
  type = {Unpublished manuscript},
  institution = {Test Institution},
}

@presentation{test2,
  author = {Doe, John},
  eventdate = {2023-08-23/2023-08-25},
  title = {Sample title},
  titleaddon = {Paper presentation},
  eventtitle = {Test Event},
  venue = {Test Venue},
}
```

[image]

I am not sure whether this has something to do with the entry types, but `@thesis` and `@presentation` are the types I am working with.

Comment: Please post the MWE in full format, refer https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Looks like a bug in `biblatex-apa`. As a workaround, you can switch to `date` instead of `eventdate` in the second reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably report this at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues. [When guidance in `biblatex-apa-test-references.bib` is to use `eventdate` for `@presentation` entries](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/6e4678d2594275cf4b0070fa56927206c70c4d54/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib#L1497-L1506), `biblatex-apa` should also take this into account when sorting.

For now, you can add the following redefinition of the sorting template to include `eventdate` info when sorting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{apa}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{pubstate}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \field{eventyear}
    \literal{-2000000000}% APA has "nodates" coming first
  }
  \sort{
    \field{month}
    \field{eventmonth}
    \literal{-2000000000}% APA has "nodates" coming first
  }
  \sort{
    \field{day}
    \field{eventday}
    \literal{-2000000000}% APA has "nodates" coming first
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{test1,
  author = {Doe, John},
  year = 2022,
  title = {Test title},
  type = {Unpublished manuscript},
  institution = {Test Institution},
}

@presentation{test2,
  author = {Doe, John},
  eventdate = {2023-08-23/2023-08-25},
  title = {Sample title},
  titleaddon = {Paper presentation},
  eventtitle = {Test Event},
  venue = {Test Venue},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Doe, J. (2022). Test title [Unpublished manuscript]. Test Institution. Doe, J. (2023, August 23–25). Sample title [Paper presentation]. Test Event, Test Venue.]

Comment: You can track the issue [here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/233); I have also linked your workaround. Cheers!